# How to get another kubernetes container's system metrics(cpu, memory, etc.)?

Tags: kubernetes, containers

There's 1 kubernetes pod(2 containers - container1, container2)

Is there any solution to get container1's metrics(cpu, memory, network, etc.) from container2?

Comment: Are you already using a monitoring solution such as Prometheus ?

Comment: @aboitier no, i'm not using that solutions. I am wondering this question in low level.